# MVC3 data in jQuery dialog is not posting back to server

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am a pretty new to MVC3, but I am writing an MVC3 app needs to load a List of DateTime in a jQuery dialog box, but when I go to post back to the server, the List of DateTime does not get sent.

I tired adding in a hidden element for each of the dates in the list like this

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.ListOfDates.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ListOfDates[i])
}
```

but then I get the following error when trying to change the date in the jQuery datepicker:

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to set value of the property
>   'currentDay': object is null or undefined

Could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?  I have created a test app to demonstrate:

Model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Stupid_Dates_Test.Models
{
    public class Model
    {
        public string StringProperty { get; set; }
        public int IntProperty { get; set; }
        public List<DateTime> ListOfDates { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Stupid_Dates_Test.Models;

namespace Stupid_Dates_Test.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            Model m = new Model();
            m.StringProperty = "This is a string property";
            m.IntProperty = 100;
            m.ListOfDates = new List<DateTime>();
            m.ListOfDates.Add(new DateTime(2012, 11, 1));
            m.ListOfDates.Add(new DateTime(2012, 11, 2));
            m.ListOfDates.Add(new DateTime(2012, 11, 3));
            m.ListOfDates.Add(new DateTime(2012, 11, 4));
            m.ListOfDates.Add(new DateTime(2012, 11, 5));
            return View(m);
        }

        public void Save(Model m)
        {
            // Save Code
        }
    }
}
```

View

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="../../Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

@model Stupid_Dates_Test.Models.Model
<form id="frmMain" action="">
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.StringProperty)
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.IntProperty)

@*@for (int i = 0; i < Model.ListOfDates.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ListOfDates[i])
}*@

<a href="javascript:ShowDates()">Edit List of Dates</a>
<div id="dlgDates" style="display: none;">
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.ListOfDates.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.ListOfDates[i])
    }
</div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var today = new Date();
        var dd = today.getDate();
        var mm = today.getMonth() + 1;
        var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
        if (dd < 10) { dd = '0' + dd }
        if (mm < 10) { mm = '0' + mm }
        today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
        $(":input[data-datepicker]").datepicker({ defaultDate: today });
    });

    function ShowDates() {
        $("#dlgDates").dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            closeOnEscape: false,
            width: 500,
            height: 400,
            resizable: false,
            title: "Dates",
            modal: true,
            draggable: false,
            open: function () {
                $("#dlgDates").show();
            },
            buttons: {
                "Save": function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: '/Home/Save/',
                        data: $("#frmMain").serialize(),
                        success: function () {
                            // Save Code
                            alert('Saved successfully!');
                            $('#dlgDates').dialog('destroy');
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            alert('Error');
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

DateTime Editor Template

```
@model System.DateTime
@Html.TextBox("", (Model == null ? "" : Convert.ToDateTime(ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue).ToShortDateString()), new { data_datepicker = true })
```

Comment: you have a mismatched Razor comment (`*@`) in your code (after closing the `@for`). Also, you could use the helper `using(Html.BeginForm()){ ... }` instead of manually creating the `form` tag

Comment: Fixed the razor comment, I just forgot to copy in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues associated:
1) the selector is wrong. :input[data-datepicker] selects the inputs with type="date-datepicker" as my understanding. Html.TextBoxFor render an input whose type is "text", try add a class to the input fields so that you can use something like input.datepck to select them.

2) When you use the jQuery dialog plugin, the dates fields are not being sent to the server (they don't show in the http request